using sfinae to select function/constructor only if type has member
I am trying to allow construction of my class only from a type that has a size() member. I tried 2 approches:
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

// Approach #1
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct HasSize : std::false_type { }; 
template <typename T>
struct HasSize <T, decltype((void) T::size)> : std::true_type { };
template <typename C>
inline constexpr bool has_size1_v = HasSize<C>::value;

// Approach #2
template <typename C>
inline constexpr bool has_size2_v =
    std::is_integral_v<decltype(std::declval<C&>().size())>;

class MySpan {
 public:
  MySpan() = default;
  MySpan(std::size_t len) {}

// ********
  template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<has_size1_v<T>>>
//   template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<has_size2_v<T>>>
// ********
  MySpan(T&& c) : MySpan(c.size()) {}
};

void foo(long) {}

template <typename T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, MySpan>>>
void foo(T v) { MySpan s(v); }

struct MyStruct {
  int size() { return 0; }
};

int main() {
    int i;
    foo(i);
}

static_assert(has_size1_v<MyStruct>); // fails
static_assert(has_size2_v<MyStruct>); // ok

Nither approach really works. As you can see at the end, approach #1 fails the static assert for some reason. But approach #1 sort of works - when I enable it in the part marked with ********, the code in main compiles fine.
When I switch to approach #2 (in the part marked ********) main fails to compile.
You can see this all here: https://godbolt.org/z/GM5PPcYz3
I am confused as to why each approach works in one place but fails in the other, and also would like to find a way that works everywhere

See if this helps: How can you check whether a templated class has a member function?

struct HasSize <T, decltype((void) &T::size)> : std::true_type { }; seems to fix it. Note the ampersand. T::size is not a valid expression having a type when size is a non-static member function of T; whereas &T::size is. Note though that has_size1_v  would be true for a type where size is a static function or a data member or a non-static function taking one or more parameters, which is probably not what you want.
